# Apache .htaccess -> Nginx config

Tags: apache, nginx

I am just started looking into using Nginx over Apache into my own LAMP stack. But I use a number of frameworks (CakePHP) which use .htaccess files.

What I don't understand is if I need to convert theses files into something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess will not be useful to nginx. You need to convert them to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf like files.

Here is a start for pretty URLs with CakePHP (official doc):

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#pretty-urls-on-nginx

Note: generally, you'll add a yoursite.conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/